# How to count the elements of a sparse matrix in a certain region?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix and want to divide the region into 4 parts, dividing x and y in 2 equidistant pieces and want to calculate the sum of the corresponding values.

For the example below, the coordinates x-y each corresponds to [0,16] so the region is a square. There is a sparse matrix in this square, which is symmetrical. I would like to divide the region into smaller squares and sum up the sparse values. Region 0:8,0:8 has 2 elements and their values are both (2,3)=(3,2)=8 so the sum is 16.

Summation of the 1st region should give `16`, 2nd and 3rd are `36` and the 4th one is `26`.

```
x = sparse(16,16);
x   (3,2)    =    8;
x  (10,2)    =    8;
x  (13,2)    =    8;
x  (14,2)    =    4;
x  (15,2)    =    4;
x   (2,3)    =    8;
x  (10,3)    =    4;
x  (13,3)    =    4;
x  (14,3)    =    2;
x  (15,3)    =    2;
x   (2,10)   =    8;
x   (3,10)   =    4;
x  (13,10)   =    4;
x  (14,10)   =    2;
x  (15,10)   =    2;
x   (2,13)   =    8;
x   (3,13)   =    4;
x  (10,13)   =    4;
x  (14,13)   =    2;
x  (15,13)   =    2;
x   (2,14)   =    4;
x   (3,14)   =    2;
x  (10,14)   =    2;
x  (13,14)   =    2;
x  (15,14)   =    1;
x   (2,15)   =    4;
x   (3,15)   =    2;
x  (10,15)   =    2;
x  (13,15)   =    2;
x  (14,15)   =    1;
```

i would rather appriciate a shorter way, rather than writing a line for each sub-square. lets say for 6000 sub-squares one should write 6000 lines?

Comment: How do you define the term "equidistant "?

Comment: How do you divide a `15-by-15` array into 4 equal quadrants? The best we can do is `7x7`+`7x8`+`8x7`+`8x8`. In other words - how do you split the array when you have an odd number of elements in a certain direction?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to ask is **code generate a sparse matrix** where summation of the 1st region should give 16, 2nd and 3rd are 36 and the 4th one is 26. If its ok - please edit your question. Moreover, don't expect other to write complete code so put some code sample where you're stuck.

Comment: nope, i already have the sparse matrix , so no need to generate. I would like to know if there is a practical way to calculate the sum of the elements located at specific regions.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the input in a more convenient way:

```
X = sparse([...
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4
      0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2
      0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1
      0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]);
```

For convenience, we first make the array dimensions even. We don't use `padarray()` for this because this makes the sparse matrix full!

```
sz = size(X);
newX = sparse(sz(1)+1,sz(2)+1);

padTopLeft = true; % < chosen arbitrarily
if padTopLeft  
  newX(2:end,2:end) = X;
else % bottom right
  newX(1:sz(1),1:sz(2)) = X;   
end
%% Preallocate results:
sums = zeros(2,2,2);
```

#### Method #1: `accumarray`

We create a mask of the form:

```
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

and then use it to sum the appropriate elements of `newX`:

```
sums(:,:,1) = reshape(...
                accumarray(reshape(repelem([1,2;3,4], ceil(sz(1)/2), ceil(sz(2)/2)),[],1),...
                           reshape(newX,                                            [],1),...
              [],@sum) ,2,2);
```

#### Method #2: `blockproc` (requires the Image Processing Toolbox)

```
sums(:,:,2) = blockproc(full(newX), ceil(sz/2), @(x)sum(x.data(:)));
```

#### Several notes:

1. I also tried `histcounts2`, which is very short, but it only tells you the *amount* of values in each quadrant, not their sum:

   ```
   [r,c] = find(newX);
   histcounts2(r,c,[2,2])
   ```
2. I might've overcomplicated the `accumarray` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very precise and you don't made any efford to find a solution, here is what you are asking..

```
clear;clc;close;

Matrix=rand(20,20);
Acc=zeros(1,4);

Acc(1)=sum(sum( Matrix(1:size(Matrix,1)/2,1:size(Matrix,2)/2) ));
Acc(2)=sum(sum( Matrix((size(Matrix,1)/2)+1:end,1:size(Matrix,2)/2)));
Acc(3)=sum(sum( Matrix(1:size(Matrix,1)/2,((size(Matrix,2)/2)+1):end )));
Acc(4)=sum(sum( Matrix((size(Matrix,1)/2)+1:end,((size(Matrix,2)/2)+1):end)));

% Verification
sum(sum(Matrix)) % <- is the same with
sum(Acc)         % <- this
```

Comment: `round(size(Matrix,1)/2)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. let me clarify. I have the coordinates x-y, each corresponds to [0,16] so the region is a square. There is a sparse matrix in this square, which is symmetrical. I would like to divide the region into smaller squares and sum up the sparse values. Region 0:8,0:8 has 2 elements and their values are both (2,3)=(3,2)=8 so the sum is 16. hope clear now. dividing into 4 regions is dummy. I just wanted to put a simple case. Hence, i would rather appriciate a shorter way,rather than writing a line for each sub-square. lets say for 6000 sub-squares one should write 6000 lines?

Comment: From the information you gave earlier, that was the answer, now you changed the requirements...

Answer (score 0):

You can define any rectangle within the matrix by defining the 4 corners of it. Then use a `for` loop to process all rectangles.

```
regions = [
     1  8  1  8
     9 16  1  8
     1  8  9 16
     9 16  9 16
     ];

regionsum = zeros(size(regions,1),1);
for rr = 1:size(regions,1)
    submat = x(regions(rr,1):regions(rr,2),regions(rr,3):regions(rr,4));
    regionsum(rr) = sum(submat(:));
end

>> regionsum

regionsum =

    16
    36
    36
    26
```

If you mean you want to divide the square matrix into 2^N (N>2) squares of the same size then you can write `regions` with a for loop.

```
N = 1; % 2^N-by-2^N sub-squares
L = size(x,1);

dL = L/(2^N);
assert(dL==int32(dL),'Too many divisions')

segments = zeros(2^N,2);
for nn = 1:2^N
    segments(nn,:) = [1,dL]+dL*(nn-1);
end
regions = zeros(2^(2*N),4);
for ss = 1:2^N
    for tt = 1:2^N
        regions((2^N)*(ss-1) + tt,:) = [segments(ss,:),segments(tt,:)];
    end
end
```

example output with dividing into 16 (N=2) square submatrices:

```
>> regions

regions =

     1     4     1     4
     1     4     5     8
     1     4     9    12
     1     4    13    16
     5     8     1     4
     5     8     5     8
     5     8     9    12
     5     8    13    16
     9    12     1     4
     9    12     5     8
     9    12     9    12
     9    12    13    16
    13    16     1     4
    13    16     5     8
    13    16     9    12
    13    16    13    16

>> regionsum

regionsum =

    16
     0
    12
    24
     0
     0
     0
     0
    12
     0
     0
     8
    24
     0
     8
    10

>>
```

Comment: looks like that it would work. let me play with it a bit. many thanks !!